# Is there a function to pass image name on click to a modal window?

Tags: image, variables

I'm creating a page with multiple unique images that when the image is clicked on opens a modal window with a bigger version of the image. All of this would be done with a style sheet containing base64 data-URIs. With the help of some folks here I was able to create https://jsfiddle.net/o8cvtyr4/

With https://jsfiddle.net/dx9zeta7/ I get a start.

```
<img onclick="changeIt(this)" src="" class="A" border="0" align="bottom" 
border="0">

<img onclick="changeIt(this)" 
src="https://dummyimage.com/120x186/e8df66/fcfcfc&text=B" class="B" 
border="0" align="bottom" border="0">
```

The "A" example is the way I called the image using Class="A" and the image src = a transparent image.

The "B" example uses a regular image as source.

The "C" example uses the base64 data-URI.

As I mentioned in the other thread about base64 data-URIs I want to call the image data from a style sheet so that the html document is easier the edit with muliple base64 images.

I borrowed some code I found to test this idea with the image source in an alert window, but the image should pop up in the modal window.

I expect the modal window to contain the image of the one that is clicked on. These images would be contained in a table with cells for each image

Comment: Create a hidden modal containing an `img` tag. After clicking the displayed img set the src of img tag inside the modal and set display to something (eg block) of modal through the `changeIt()` function.

Comment: If I do 

        <div><img style="width: 389px; height: 594px;"
        onclick="changeIt(this)" src="" class="A"
        name="bigview" border="0"></div>


I get "A" to work. Can I pass the Class name so I get "B" or "C" when clicked?